# embed javascript function in html

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I want to use a confirm box for user to check before submitting the form. I use the following form tag in my script:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="POST" target="_blank" onsubmit="return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete it from the database?\");">
```

But it is not working, after I click "submit" button, the "delete.php" will be executed. Can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong? I wonder is it because this "confirm" function is some sort of inline style that I need to do some reference in the `<head>` tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it from the database?');"
```

Tested, and works. I don't think you can escape characters like that in tags.

Comment: Ah, I don't know how I overlooked the escape char.  An escape char will create throw an error in html.  The escape char can only be used in a JS only environment.